# How do I make an sbt plugin for compiler plugin with cross build support

Tags: sbt

I have an sbt-plugin that updates scalac options to add a compiler-plugin. With the release of Scala 2.11 I need to change the version of the compiler-plugin depending on the version of scala being used in the users project.

I understand that SBT itself uses 2.10 regardless, so I think therefore my sbt-plugin should only be compiled with 2.10.

However, I change the version of the compile- plugin I pass to the build at runtime. At the moment I do this:

`val instrumentSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = { Seq(
     libraryDependencies += "group" %% "artifact" % "version % "scope,
  ) }`

Is this the right thing to do? I have only one sbt-plugin release (2.10) and and it tries to find the correct compiler-plugin version (either 2.10 or 2.11) at runtime.

In addition the sbt-plugin itself uses the compiler-plugin, so I declare that in build.sbt as a normal dependency. In this case the sbt-plugin will only ever use the 2.10 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what the actual questions are, but here are some thoughts that came to my mind:

- sbt plugins are dependent libraries on your build project, which will not affect your actual project code or classpath. So your plugins for sbt 0.13 series are published to Scala 2.10.
- Scala compiler plugins are jars passed into `scalacOptions`. sbt is able to manage that for you by declaring library dependencies on "plugin" configurations. See [Compiler Plugin Support](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Compiler-Plugins.html).

So something like this should work:

```scala
val instrumentSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
  libraryDependencies += "com.example" %% "foo_plugin" % "0.1.0" % "plugin",
  scalacOptons += ("-Pfoo:base-directory:" + (scalaSource in Compile).value.getAbsolutePath)
)
```

Comment: I think the `scalaSource in Compile` is what I was looking for. I need only one sbt-plugin (because sbt is ONLY 2.10), and then I use the above to vary the version of the compiler-plugin. Check out sbt-scoverage 0.98.4 if you're interested which I published an hour ago.